# Stop toastr notification running on page load ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, toastr

Im catching the Html.ValidationSummary in a toastr notification which works fine, Issue i have is that it keeps showing a blank error toastr notification in on page load.

Ive removed the onload class from my body tag in the page layout, but no luck.

Source,

```
        var message = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(((@Html.ValidationSummary()==null)?"":@Html.ValidationSummary().ToHtmlString())));
if (message.length > 0) {
    toastr.error(message);
    }
```

Comment: Try `toastr.remove();` in `document.ready`

Comment: no luck, any other ideas? this just removes it completely.